# I want to copy the data in (wchar_t *)buffer but i am unable to do so bcz there are other incompatible types,typecasting but not getting the result?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to print buffer data at one instance avoiding all other wprintf instances but unable to convert data in compatible type with buffer.

Have a look at code:

Kindly tell me how to get through it:

```
DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    PEVT_VARIANT pRenderedValues = NULL;
    WCHAR wsGuid[50];
    LPWSTR pwsSid = NULL;

    //
    // Beginning of functional Logic
    //
    for (;;)
    {

        if (!EvtRender(hContext, hEvent, EvtRenderEventValues, dwBufferSize, pRenderedValues, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount))
        {
            if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (status = GetLastError()))
            {
                dwBufferSize = dwBufferUsed;
                dwBytesToWrite = dwBufferSize;
                pRenderedValues = (PEVT_VARIANT)malloc(dwBufferSize);
                if (pRenderedValues)
                {
                    EvtRender(hContext, hEvent, EvtRenderEventValues, dwBufferSize, pRenderedValues, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("malloc failed\n");
                    status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Buffer = (wchar_t*) malloc (1*wcslen(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal));

        //
        // Print the values from the System section of the element.
        wcscpy(Buffer,pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal);

        int i = wcslen(Buffer);

        if (NULL != pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderGuid].GuidVal)
        {
            StringFromGUID2(*(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderGuid].GuidVal), wsGuid, sizeof(wsGuid)/sizeof(WCHAR));
            wcscpy(Buffer+i,(wchar_t*)pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderGuid].GuidVal);
            wprintf(L"Provider Guid: %s\n", wsGuid);
        }
```

//Getting "??????" on screen after inclusion of guidval tell me the correct way to copy it??

```
        wprintf(L"Buffer = %ls",Buffer);
```

//Also tell the way to copy unsigned values into buffer

```
        wprintf(L"EventID: %lu\n", EventID);

        wprintf(L"Version: %u\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemVersion].ByteVal);
        wprintf(L"Level: %u\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemLevel].ByteVal);


        wprintf(L"EventRecordID: %I64u\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemEventRecordId].UInt64Val);

        if (EvtVarTypeNull != pRenderedValues[EvtSystemActivityID].Type)
        {
            StringFromGUID2(*(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemActivityID].GuidVal), wsGuid, sizeof(wsGuid)/sizeof(WCHAR));
            wprintf(L"Correlation ActivityID: %s\n", wsGuid);
        }

        if (EvtVarTypeNull != pRenderedValues[EvtSystemRelatedActivityID].Type)
        {
            StringFromGUID2(*(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemRelatedActivityID].GuidVal), wsGuid, sizeof(wsGuid)/sizeof(WCHAR));
            wprintf(L"Correlation RelatedActivityID: %s\n", wsGuid);
        }

        wprintf(L"Execution ProcessID: %lu\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProcessID].UInt32Val);
        wprintf(L"Execution ThreadID: %lu\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemThreadID].UInt32Val);
        wprintf(L"Channel: %s\n",pRenderedValues[EvtSystemChannel].StringVal);
        wprintf(L"Computer: %s\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemComputer].StringVal);



        //
        // Final Break Point
        //

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? It cannot be both C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

**The first error is when starting to write to the buffer:**

```
Buffer = (wchar_t*) malloc (1*wcslen(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal));
wcscpy(Buffer,pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal);
```

StringVal points to a wide character string with a trailing null byte, so you should

```
Buffer = malloc (sizeof(wchar_t)*(wcslen(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal)+1));
```

or even better

```
Buffer = wcsdup(pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal);
```

**Second error is when appending the GUID.**

You are not allocating enough memory, you are just appending to the already full Buffer. And you are appending the raw GUID, not the GUID string. You should replace

```
int i = wcslen(Buffer);
wcscpy(Buffer+i,(wchar_t*)pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderGuid].GuidVal);
```

with something like

```
// Attention: memory leak if realloc returns NULL! So better use a second variable for the return code and check that before assigning to Buffer.
Buffer = realloc(Buffer, wcslen(Buffer) + wcslen(wsGuid) + 1);
wcscat(Buffer,wsGuid);
```

**Also:**

Besides, you should do better error checking for EvtRender. And you should check dwPropertyCount before accessing pRenderedValues[i].

BTW, `wprintf(L"Buffer = %s",Buffer);` (with %s instead of %ls) is sufficient with wprintf.

And to your last question: if you want to append unsigned values to a buffer you can use `wsprintf` to write to a string. If you can do it C++-only then you should consider using `std::wstring`. This is much easier for you with regard to allocating the buffers the right size.

Comment: Well in output i am getting the correct string for pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderName].StringVal,but in case of pRenderedValues[EvtSystemProviderGuid].GuidVal, i am getting garbage text,and Evt render error check is okey as previously i was printing everything on console,how can i get it appropriately in a buffer??

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail: If you think my answer answers your question, then please accept it. Thanks.